# div with a large z-index is under the div with a smaller z-index

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, z-index, overlapping

I had a problem:

Element  overlapped element  because it has a higher z-index (10 vs 5). Element  has the child elements #sub-block-1 & #sub-block-2, and #sub-block-1 had child text #text1 with z-index = 20. But #text1 with z-index = 20 still under  with z-index = 10. **Why?**

**Tell me, how can I solve this problem?**

*The  must have a predefined z-index (number, not 'auto', and less than z-index , for example, 5 vs 10).*

---

My example:
https://jsfiddle.net/nynsjv3L/1/

P.S.
The above example is not displayed correctly in jsfiddle - the position of the elements (#sub-block-1 & #sub-block-2) does not work.

```css
body {
  background: #00ff00;
}

.screen {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #ffffff;
  opacity: 0.75;
  z-index: 10;
}

#main-block {
  position: absolute;
  left: 500px;
  top: 200px;
  width: 700px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 2px solid #bb0000;
  background: #ff0000;
  z-index: 5;
}

.sub-block {
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  background: #ffffff;
  border: 4px solid #000000;
}

#sub-block-1 {
  left: 100;
  top: 100;
  z-index: auto;
}

#sub-block-2 {
  left: 275;
  top: 175;
  z-index: 11;
}

#text1 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 65px;
  top: 55px;
  color: #000000;
  background: #ffff00;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 700;
  z-index: 20;
}

#text2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 65px;
  top: 55px;
  color: #00bbbb;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<div id='main-block'>
  <div class='sub-block' id='sub-block-1'>
    <div id='text1'>TEST TEXT</div>
  </div>
  <div class='sub-block' id='sub-block-2'>
    <div id='text2'>NEW TEXT</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class='screen'></div>
```

Comment: **z-index** is relative to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context

Comment: z-index's apply to all elements on the same level in the same parent direct - so in you case as main-block has a lower z-index than screen - screen will appear above main-block and all it's children (as the main-block children z-index will not count against screens z-index)

Comment: Start by reading [What No One Told You About Z-Index](https://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/) to get an understanding of where the problem lies.

Answer (score 2):

The `#text` is still inside your block, that has a lower index than its sibling. The `#text` part is still in the same context block of its parent. You could check out the inner workings of z-indexes in [this page](https://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/).

You need to create a new stacking context for the text to appear above the other block. One of the possible ways is to change the opacity of the text to `.99`, or using the `transform` attribute. I do not recommend you to do it, though, as it will cause more troubles in the future.

Z-indexes should not be used very often. It is better to organize this inside the HTML itself. You should rethink your work.

Answer (score 1):

`#main-block` is on the same level as `.screen` and has a lower `z-index`. So child elements of `#main-block` will always be overlapped by `.screen` and its children.

Whenever you set an element to be `position: relative` or `position: absolute` you open up a new `z-index`-stack for all of its children.

You either have to move the child elements of `#main-block` some levels up to make them independent or give the `#main-block` a higher `z-index` which will also result in overlapping `.screen`.

**Hint**: Negative `z-index` is also possible. And clean up your markup (keyword: single quotes). ;-)

Comment: Ok, but how can I move a child element to a new z-index content (when both the child and its parents already have 'position' style)?

Comment: You’d have to change your HTML. I don’t know what you are trying to do in detail, but I would strongly recommend to rethink if there is a better approach since absolute positioning is kind of a steamroller tactic anyway.